# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use product.set() instead

Tags: python, django

i'm building a small webstore , in the product page i put the order form using FormMixin and TemplateView, when i submit the order i get a "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use product.set() instead." error

Bellow you can check the code

**Models.py**

```
 from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, )
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    nominal_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='prix normal',)
    reduced_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/products/", default="img/products/user_default.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
address = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True)
phone = models.IntegerField()
city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField(null=True)

class Order (models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderProduct')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Views.py**

```
class ProductDetailView(FormMixin, TemplateView):
model = Product
template_name = 'product.html'
form_class = OrderForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('index')

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if context['form'].is_valid():
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, name=self.kwargs['product_name'])
        customer = form.save()
        Order.objects.create(product=product, customer=customer)

    return super(TemplateView, self)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['product'] = Product.objects.get(name=self.kwargs['product_name'])
    context['form'] = self.get_form()
    return context
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Did i missed something

Comment: Please provide the entire error message beginning with the word 'Traceback'.  Post this error report into your question as code, so that we can see the full issue.

Comment: @itprorh66 i put the entire error on the question :)

Comment: Show us how do you pass the product_name? and make sure that is a valid product name and exists in your db.

Comment: @Sumithran
I found the problem,
i should put         
product = get_object_or_404(Product, product__name=self.kwargs['product_name']) instead of :
        product = get_object_or_404(Order, product__name=self.kwargs['product_name'])

now i get a new message error telling me that " 'super' object has no attribute 'get' "

Comment: post your updates on the view and share the new error traceback

Comment: @Sumithran I edited my question and my views.py file.
now the error i get is : Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use product.set() instead.

Answer (score 0):

For handling many-to-many relations, you cannot directly set the `product` from `Order`. Also you would need to create the `order` first before you can set or add a product:

```
order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)
order.product.add(product)
```